# Numpy array vs. C++ vector in memory efficiency

Tags: python, c++, numpy

Which object is generally smaller in memory given the exact same data: a numpy array with dtype int64 or a C++ vector of type int? For example:

```
v = np.array([34, 23])
std::vector<int> v { 34,23 };
```

Comment: I would guess the C++ vector -- numpy arrays are likely to carry around more metadata (as python types which are pretty big compared to C types).    With that said, the memory usage difference is likely to be small (insignificant) unless you're making LOTS of arrays.

Comment: Don't forget the overhead you'll have to incur to use one of these data types from the other language.

Comment: On most modern C++ implementations that I'm aware of, `int` is 32 bits. If you want a 64 bit type, use `std::int64_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There effectively 2 parts to an `np.array` - the object overhead plus attributes like shape and strides, and a data buffer.  The first has roughly the same size for all arrays, the second scales with the number of elements (and the size of each element).  In `numpy` the data buffer is 1d, regardless of the array shape.

With only 2 elements the overhead part of your example array is probably larger than the databuffer.  But with 1000s of elements the size proportion goes the other way.

Saving the array with `np.save` will give a rough idea of the memory use.  That file format writes a header buffer (256 bytes?), and the rest is the databuffer.

I'm less familiar with C++ storage, though I think that's more transparent (if you know the language).

But remember efficiency in storing one array is only part of the story. In practice you need to think about the memory use when doing math and indexing.  The `ndarray` distinction between `view` and `copy` makes it harder to predict just how much memory is being used.

```
In [1155]: np.save('test.npy',np.array([1,2]))

In [1156]: ls -l test.npy
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul paul 88 Jun 30 17:08 test.npy

In [1157]: np.save('test.npy',np.arange(1000))

In [1158]: ls -l test.npy
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul paul 4080 Jun 30 17:08 test.npy
```

This looks like 80 bytes of header, and 4*len bytes for the data.

Comment: Indeed the point about efficiency being a relative notion is the key here. `std::vector<T>` is a compile-time optimized, guaranteed-contiguous super-thin wrapper around memory it allocates – but it has none of the vector/tensor ops or optimized I/O utilities you get out-of-the-box when you use a `numpy.ndarray` (to say nothing of OpenCL extensions built on NumPy’s API and other such things)… if you can implement your algorithm with `std::vector<T>` it’s hard to beat; it is worth remembering that it’s not a perfect fit for most cases without doing a bit of big-O work first.